# Should I empty the wrongly filled fields or leave as user has filled after validation message?

Tags: mobile-application, validation, user-expectation

In our mobile applications (intended for Android and iOS platforms), we have fields that should be filled by users.

If the user fills the field not in required format what should I
do

1. show the validation message and empty the field, or
2. show the validation message and leave the field as the user initially filled it, letting him edit his old records?

Comment: I'll just link this here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/402889/22184

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Typing on mobile is a very arduous and unpleasant process, so we should try keeping it to a minimum.

Sometimes your users will have made just a small error that can be fixed by replacing or adding a character or two (typically they typed something instead of @ in an email address etc.). Sometimes they will have made a big error and they need to retype the whole thing. So unless you have a way of knowing or making an *educated* guess as to which type of error will be more common with your users and your type of data - it seems like there's no way of knowing. However, small mistakes are much more common by nature.

Even if we say that we have no way to know this, deleting an entire field on mobile is still much easier for the user than entering an entire field - you just hold the Delete key. So if we *keep* the data, those who would've preferred that we clear the field have a small price to pay for our decision, since the field is deleted easily. But if we *clear* the data, those users who would've preferred that we keep it, have a high price to pay - they need to retype everything.

Seems to me that keeping the data is definitely the safer way to go.

Comment: It's also good to show them what they had so they don't make the same mistakes twice.

Comment: Also true for non-mobile.

Comment: With touch, you don't even need to hold the delete key on some devices/browsers - I can long-press the field and "clear all"

Comment: Exception: password fields (where you don't see what you typed anyway). And fields that the user should type in twice to ensure correctness (I'd suggest to maybe keep one and clear the other). And of course captchas ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah a password is hidden, so it's not like it would matter... UNLESS you have a "reveal password" checkbox/icon, then you should keep it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have to disagree about passwords.  Clearing the field is easy for the user, and often it's a simple mistake (such as submitting before the last character is typed).  Automatically emptying it when the user tries to correct this error is irritating as hell.

Comment: And on a desktop, it's as easy as Ctrl+A and typing over the field.

Comment: @sapi. Clearing passwords is a security concern: The incorrect password is probably only slightly incorrect, or is a password for another account. The server should *never* publish passwords, so the new copy of the page should not contain the password. (This may not apply if the validation is done client side or with Ajax.)

Comment: You can definitely get the field in focus (and select the entered text).

Answer (score 25):

From a usability point of view, definitely keep their entry. There is nothing more annoying to users, in our experience, than clearing their entry on failing validation. They need to be able to see what they have done wrong, and if you clear it they are having to use their memory.

Comment: Definitely true on non-mobile platforms as well.

Answer (score 4):

Why not provide a way for user to do both ?
Data can be left intact as suggested by others and providing a small "X" button/icon ( similar to the magnifying glass icon usually seen in search boxes) at the end of text box to clear the whole thing if the user intends to.

Comment: Said small X button should preferably be very near the magnifying glass. Also, no need for a confirmation prompt. Also, disable form submit from keyboard. Users _still_ have a 50% chance of  doing the action they intended to.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, especially for **text type input** or **textarea** field, it is better to keep the existing text upon validation error. However, depending on your actual scenario, there may be other decision making steps that you might need to consider:

- If it is in a *totally* wrong format. Example you requested for numbers and
  the user fills up the field with alphabets, clear it and show error
  message. It is meaningless to keep input that you do not want to accept.
- If it is in a *partially* wrong format. Example you want users to enter
  a description about themselves, but clearly stated that URLs are not
  accepted, remove any URLs programmatically and save the input without showing
  any error message.
- If it contains *sensitive* information. Example user entered a wrong password. Clear it and show error message upon authentication failure.
- If you detect *abnormal inputs* such as extra POST parameters, clear the form but do not show any error message. If possible, redirect user to another page or log out the user.

Comment: "remove any URLs programmatically" -- _never_ modify user input behind their back. Especially not when that involves content deletion. Especially not if you think `object.cx` is a URL rather than a piece of code.

Comment: "If you detect abnormal inputs such as extra POST parameters, clear the form but do not show any error message. If possible, redirect user to another page or log out the user." - Bad. Bad. Bad. How ever will I debug my app that's trying to interface with your app now? Unless, of course, you don't like my app trying to submit a form.

Comment: @JanDvorak, for URL detection, I tend to use a more stringent regex to minimize false positives like the one you pointed out. In the real world, there is always a trade-off between security and usability. Of course, this site is all about UX and I digressed.